# getting error while adding a system call

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04(64bit) and installed kernel version linux-2.6.37.3. My device is ASUS x201ev net-book(64 bit). I'm providing the link of procedure i used. i edited unistd_64.h file also and numbered the new call properly.

But my make process gets stuck. it says it cant find the block ( no directory) or cant find /built-in.o file in directory. the error is make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apWTm.jpg): *** [vmlinux.o] Error 1

How to solve this one? please help!

[image]

[Adding a System Call in Linux Kernel 2.6.29](https://www.dropbox.com/s/spi3c1w1jematr5/How%20to%20add%20System%20Call%20in%20Linux%20Kernel%202.6.37.3.pdf)

Comment: you need to provide it the object file. What generated this error exactly though?

Comment: No idea of object file,sorry.i added the screenshot here :https://www.dropbox.com/s/b03oha47tycp0cq/20140125_013518.png
i dont know what caused the error. i just ran 'make' command from my linux kernel.@Ramhound

Comment: solved it anyway. i dint notice that i need to install g++ again on new kernel.

Comment: The screenshot was very helpful in understanding the question.  You might have made it clear you were using the `make` command.  I would have gone down the route of verifying the contents of the file, then coming to the realization, it was expecting to have generated a file.  Some of my confusion was the fact I originally replied while being unable to access `Dropbox`.  I have placed the screenshot in the question.  I encourage you to answer your own question by documentating what you did to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for attaching the screenshot :)

I used sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get install g++. I'd installed g++ on my regular ubuntu, but forgot to install that on the older 2.6.37.3. installing g++ solved it.